# Vue 2 pass props to child [old : "call child's method"]

Tags: vuejs2, call, parent-child

ok so I've learned that I'm not supposed to call a child's method but pass it props instead.

I've got (parent) :

```
<template>
  <div id="main">
    <Header :title ="title"/>
    <router-view/>
    <LateralMenu/>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'app'
    data: function () {
      return {
        title: true
      }
    },
    methods: {
      hideTitle: function () {
        this.title = false
        console.log(this.title)
      },
      showTitle: function () {
        this.title = true
        console.log(this.title)
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

and (child) :

```
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'Header',
    props: ['title'],
    created () {
      console.log(this.title)
    },
    methods: {
    }
  }
</script>
```

the first console logs (inside the parent) print correctly on each method but the second console log within the child stays true all the time. I got this from : [Pass data from parent to child component in vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39199303/pass-data-from-parent-to-child-component-in-vue-js)

inside what method does the console.log need to be to be printed everytime the methods in the parent are triggered?

(this is why I wanted to go for method-calling, originally, by going with variables instead, we're potentially omitting valuable parts of the process such as optimization and a "when" for the execution(s!!) of our code. pontetally being the key word here, don't blow up on me, keep in mind that I'm learning.)

OLD:

> I've browsed the web and I know there a a million different answers
>   and my point is with the latest version of vue none of those millions
>   of answers work.
>
> either everything is deprecated or it just doesn't apply but I need a
>   solution.
>
> How do you call a child method?
>
> I have a 1 component = 1 file setup.
>
> DOM is declared inside a `<template>` tag javascript is written inside
>   a `<script>` tag. I'm going off of vue-cli scaffolding.
>
> latest method I've tried is @emit  (sometimes paired with an @on
>   sometimes not) doesn't work :
>
> child :
>
> ```
> <script>
>   export default {
>     name: 'Header',
>     created () {
>       this.$on('hideTitlefinal', this.hideTitlefinal)
>     },
>     methods: {
>
>       hideTitlefinal: function () {
>         console.log('hideeeee')
>       },
>       showTitlefinal: function () {
>         console.log('shwowwww')
>       }
>     }
>   }
> </script>
> ```
>
> parent :
>
> ```
> <template>
>   <div id="main">
>     <Header v-on:hideTitle="hideTitlefinal" v-on:showTitle="showTitlefinal"/>
>     <router-view/>
>     <LateralMenu/>
>   </div>
> </template>
>
> <script>
>   export default {
>     methods: {
>       hideTitle: function () {
>         this.$emit('hideTitle')
>       },
>       showTitle: function () {
>         this.$emit('showTitle')
>       }
>     }
>   }
> </script>
> ```
>
> console :
>
> ```
> Uncaught TypeError: this.$emit is not a function
>     at Object.showTitle (Main.vue?1785:74)
>     at VueComponent.showTitle (LateralMenu.vue?c2ae:113)
>     at boundFn (vue.esm.js?efeb:186)
>     at invoker (vue.esm.js?efeb:1943)
>     at HTMLDivElement.fn._withTask.fn._withTask (vue.esm.js?efeb:1778)
> ```

Comment: you don't call functions of children, you pass props. The point of reactive frameworks is to react to data. That said, it's technically possible, just a bad idea, which is why you're not able to find any docs as to how to achieve that.

Comment: ok well I don't understand what passing props would look like, could you make me an example please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please don't do this. You're thinking in terms of events. When x happens, do y. That's sooo *jquery 2005* man. Vue still has all that stuff, but we're being invited to think in terms of a view model...

You want your state in ***a*** variable, in window scope, and you want reactive pipes linking your vue stuff to your state object. To toggle visibility, use a [dynamic class binding](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html), or [v-if](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html). Then think about how to represent your state. It could be as simple as having a property like `store.titleVisible`. But, you want to 'normalize' your store, and avoid relationships between items of state. So if title visibility really depends on something higher up, like an editMode or something, then just put the higher-up thing in the store, then create computed properties if you need them.

The goal is that you don't care when things happen. You just define the relationships between the markup and the store, then let Vue take care of it. The docs will tell you to use props for parent=>child and $emit for child=>parent communication. Truth is you don't need this until you have multiple instances of a component, or reusable components. Vue stuff talks to a store, *not to other vue stuff*. For single-use components, as for your root Vue, just use the `data:`.

Whenever you find yourself writing show/hide methods, you're doing it wrong. It's intuitive (because it's procedural), but you'll quickly appreciate how much better the MVVM approach is.

Comment: I don't understand. I mean the only thing I understand is that I have the wrong approach, which I'm fully willing to admit. what is it then that a person does when doing this correctly?

Comment: First off thanks for your time and answer. Even though I still consider myself a beginner, I've done a full React-redux, react-forms MVVM project, I really did grasp the notions of components and containers. but with vue it seems to me (at first) (and I know I may be wrong) that the vue devs have lost sight of all this. or they're communicating very poorly how I'm supposed to accomplish the same things as React. but right now I'm trying to influence a "cousin" (child -> parent -> other child) and I'm in a 1 component = 1 file approach. I can't "cheat" like you can with a 1 file = whole project

Comment: also please read updated OP, I'm so close now but it still won't give. and I think I'm now doing what's a correct pattern for MVVM vue?

Comment: What I'm saying is I'd LOVE to "just do a v-if" but I can place that in my final component all I want that's not going to help it receive the variable from a cousin.

Comment: Show me your store ! The fact that you're using single file components doesn't change anything. You still need a store, according to me. You can expose component methods, have a look at $root, $children and $refs. But this is the road to hell. Something like `this.$root.$children[1].hideTitle()` will let you call your method. But then what have you got. A fresh steaming mess is what :-)

Comment: I don't have a store. I'm trying to keep things on the low-down and accessible. are you saying contrary to react vue wants to cut all bridges to making store-less applications?

Comment: I don't know how store works in vue yet. to the best of my understanding it's placed within the root component?

Comment: [Here's the page on state management.](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html). Perhaps you need to go away and have a really bad time, then come back and create a store :-)

Comment: no I'll give way and add a store. but seriously could the Vue doc be any more poorly written? I mean seriously. it talks about stuff that it ends up saying is irrelevant in light of another library called vuex which it turns out https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/1026 is NOT a store. so how is that doc teaching you to do store??? if that's not the doc teaching you to do store then where is it? why do people keep linking to this as if there's any relevant info therein. there's not. also apparently (and I had to learn this browsing stack) most people choose redux for vue anyways.

Comment: oh and they added a #react section since last I saw it where they say that vuex basically IS redux. what ???

Comment: Leave vuex til later. Just use a plain javascript object, but make sure you only have *one*. Call it store, or vueStore, and just put everything in there. Start structuring it more when you need to, but not before (arborescence, mutation methods, then perhaps vuex). Vue without a store is a bit like a string puppet without the strings.

Comment: thanks I'll do that. If you can do you have a link where this is represented. For all my google fu, I've been furiously googling this for a month, noone has thought to paste an example. ESPECIALLY not the docs. which blows my mind. I mean if anything the vue docs are incomplete. their example doesn't work.