# Vue: how do I pass down data from my parent component to required child components?

Tags: vue.js

In my root component (app.js), I have data, `activeTab`, that I want to pass down to Topbar.  How do I do this from within the app.js file I have here?

**app.js**

```
window.Vue = require('vue');


Vue.component('Topbar', require('./components/Topbar.vue').default);


new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        activeTab: "cart"
    },
    methods: {
        handleTabChange: function(tab) {
           this.activeTab = tab
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Is there a top-level template that you're not showing us?

Comment: @WW. there is a blade file (php view) where I have: <div id = "app">  <Topbar></Topbar></div>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass data from parent to child component in vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39199303/pass-data-from-parent-to-child-component-in-vue-js)

Answer (score 0):

props are what you need to pass down data. see [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html)