# Pass variable down to VueJS component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I need to pass down a variable to a component. My setup is like this:

Main: **Meet.vue**

```
<html>
 <div class="carousel-cell">
    <Category :searchTerm="woman"></Category>
    </div>
 <div class="carousel-cell">
    <Category :searchTerm="men"></Category>
    </div>
[..]
<script>
import Category from './Category'
export default {
  components: {
    Category
  },
```

Sub: **Category.vue**:

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      search: [how to access the **searchTerm** here?]
```

How to access the **searchTerm** `<Category :searchTerm="woman"></Category>` from Meet.vue in Category.vue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39199303/pass-data-from-parent-to-child-component-in-vue-js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to introduce this `searchTerm` property in your Category component as described in the [VueJS Documentation](https://fr.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html)

In `Category.vue`

```
export default {
  props: ['searchTerm'],

  // Your component code (computed, methods, watch, ...)
}
```

If you want to apply some validation on your prop

```
export default {
  props: {
    searchTerm: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
      // If not required, it's possible to give a default value
      default: "woman"
    },
  }

  // Your component code (computed, methods, watch, ...)
}
```

You can then read your prop with `this.searchTerm`.
You can also directly read it inside `<template></template>` with `{{ searchTerm }}` for example.

---

If at some point you'll need to write on one of your prop, it is best to copy it's value on a local variable and work with it

```
props: ['searchTerm'],
data: function () {
  return {
    // Write on search variable if needed
    search: this.searchTerm
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this example. Is there a way to pass the **searchTerm** after it changed in the **meet.vue**? I tried __v-bind__ without success: `<div class="carousel-cell">
<Category v-bind="search" :searchTerm="search"></Category>`  
The search term gets updated from the search box within meet.vue:             `<v-text-field
              v-model="search"
              label="Search it..."           
              ></v-text-field>` 
</div>`

Comment: @Tom I suggest you to watch your prop in your Category component. You can have an example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44584292/vuejs-2-0-how-to-listen-for-props-changes - and you can check the documentation to understand how it works : https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-vs-Watched-Property

Answer (score 1):

You are using [props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html), so the answer is:

```
export default{
    props: ['searchTerm'],
```

it can then be used directly.

Answer (score 1):

Do as below while calling the `Category` component.

`<Category :search="woman"></Category>`

Here `:search:"woman"` means pass `woman` as value to the property of `Category` component.

Then in `Category` component:

```
export default {
  props: {
    search: {type: string, required: true}
    //Here it will give error if the search is passed anything but string
    //And if search is not passed it will give error. 
  }
  //Everything else
```

or

```
export default {
  props: [search], //No checking of data type and it's not requried
  //Everything else
```