# Initializing a variable of a child from a parent

Tags: vue.js

I have a variable in my parent component and would like it to be sent to the child component.
I tried several ways but nothing works on my side, here is my code:

Parent :

```
<template>
    <Widget/>
</template>

<script>
import Widget from './Widget'

export default {
    data () {
        return {
            model: {
                data: 'data send !'
            }
        }
    },
    components: {
        Widget
    },
    methods: {
    }
}
</script>
```

Child :

```
<template>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="box">
            <p> {{data}} </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            data: '111'
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.box {
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px grey;
}
</style>
```

thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39199303/pass-data-from-parent-to-child-component-in-vue-js

Comment: I tried it with props and it doesn't work;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To bind data to a child component you can use [props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html).

Parent :

```html
<template>
  <Widget :data="model.data"/>
</template>

<script>
import Widget from "./Widget";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      model: {
        data: "data send !"
      }
    };
  },
  components: {
    Widget
  },
  methods: {}
};
</script>
```

Child:

```html
<template>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="box">
      <p>{{data}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["data"]
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.box {
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px grey;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Im sorry there was a typo in the answer I fixed it